# Logic php condition sum of the divisors

Tags: php, algorithm, function, logic

I have an array of numbers 1 until 100 and I need to find a list of numbers applying two conditions, first sum of divisors is greater than itself and second condition no subset of divisors can not sums the number itself
for that I have the php code

```
  $arrayNumbers = [];
   //array numbers 1 - 100
    $a = 1;
    $b = 100;

        for ($n = $a; $n <= $b; $n++) {
            $conditionOne = false; // Condition one: sum of the divisors greater than ifself
            $conditionTwo = false; // Condition two: No subset of those divisors sums itself
            $multiples = [];
            $subset = [];
            // Get sum of multiples divisors
            for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
                if ($n % $i == 0) 
                $multiples[]= $i;
            }
            //Condition one sum of the divisors greater than itself
            if (array_sum( $multiples ) > $n) 
                $conditionOne = true;

            foreach ($multiples as $number) {
                if ($number % 2 == 0) $subset[]= $number;
            }
            // Condition tow sum of the divisors greater than itself
            if (array_sum($subset) > $n) 
                $conditionTwo = true;
            // If first ondition one match with second condition two
            if ($conditionOne && $conditionTwo) 
                $arrayNumbers[] = $n;
        }

    echo implode('</br>$arrayNumbers );
```

Is this php logic correct? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes that looks correct, but it isn't entirely efficient. $beerstaps[] needs to be $arrayNumbers[] though.

Comment: Thanks @Nerdi.org I edited the variable.